# Mounting company server and adding files

Tags: 16.04

I have been asked to add some of my files to an internal company server and I am confused how to. The instructions I got from my boss was:

Add your files here 
From linux: /net/abc/mnt/data_drive/DataDump

Then this will mount to our web server http://abc.company.com/DataDump

I was told I have read/write access but I have no idea how to add folders under DataDump, or even to add files. I can view the link in a web browser, but that does not let me add anything. I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: If your boss gave you the location `/net/abc/mnt/data_drive/DataDump` then it sounds like the server is already mounted (otherwise you would have been given a server name/address). Have you tried simply navigating there - either in your file browser, or in the terminal (`ls /net/abc/mnt/data_drive/`)?

Comment: @steeldriver Yea I have tried that and get "no such file or directory". But I can go to Firefox/chrome and type in abc.company.com/DataDump and see all the files that are there, but unable to add my own files